# How can I Display Java Object In Spring Using Thymleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i'm newby in Spring-boot i tried to display java object in form validation
but i can't see the élément in result page
and in result page this is what i got:
result [submision 0]it can't updating the HTML elements dynamially

```js
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String Hello(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("fd", new User());
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String FormSubmit(User user) {

    return "result";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>home page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>entry your data</p>
  <form action="/create" method="POST" th:object="${fd}">

    <p>full name : <input type="text" th:filed="${fd.fullname}"></p><br>

    <p> age :<input type="text" th:filed="${fd.age}"></p><br>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="rest"></p>
  </form>



</body>

</html>
    ///////////////////////RESULTHTML/////////////
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>result page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>result submision<h1>
            <p> <span th:text="${user.fullname}"></span></p>
            <p> <span th:text="${user.age}"></span></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("result");
            mav.addObject("user", user);
            return mav;
```

for more please refer : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("result");
        mav.addObject("user", user);
        return mav;
```

for more please refer : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html